Having frontmatter openany and mainmatter openright?
In the book class, when the front matter should be openany and the main matter openright, is it correct to set the document class to openany and then use
\mainmatter
\makeatletter
\@openrighttrue
\makeatother

afterward? I came across this answer and sort of reversed it. It appears to work but am not sure if it is a "good" practice.
Thank you.

I'm not sure about standard practice or if there is one. The other way around, yes, but I've never seen a book use openany for the front matter and openright for the main. I'm not sure I've ever seen a book use openany for the front matter period. Are you sure about this? Or maybe you are packing unusual items into the frontmatter?

@cfr Thanks for the responses. This is an English (British) book from 1894. Just title pages, preface, table of contents, and list of important dates; all with no blank pages between them. It's not an issue if the blank pages are added. I'm far, far from knowledgeable in old or current typesetting standards; but I've read a lot of these old books and I'm pretty sure most of them are openany in the front matter.

Interesting. I suppose now there is almost always something on the back of key pages ....

Whether \@openrighttrue is enough (or even works) depends on the class. For the standard class book this is the case. But IMHO it is never really good practice to use internal commands of a class. Nevertheless, it can be a pragmatic or maybe the only solution.
IMHO changing the behave of \mainmatter would be better practice than adding code, i.e., non-user commands that need \makeatletter … \makeatother inside the document body (the source part between \begin{document} and \end{document}). You can use the generic command hooks of LaTeX to do the extension of \mainmatter and optional of \frontmatter from within the document preamble (the source part before \begin{document}):
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/after/frontmatter}{\@openrightfalse}% implicit switch to openany
\AddToHook{cmd/after/mainmatter}{\@openrighttrue}% explicit switch to openright
\makeatother

Some classes, like the KOMA-Script book class scrbook also provide user level options to switch from open-right, to open-any or also to open-left. So with scrbook you can use:
\AddToHook{cmd/after/frontmatter}{\KOMAoption{open}{any}}% explicit switch to open=any
\AddToHook{cmd/after/mainmatter}{\KOMAoption{open}{right}}% explicit switch to open=right

instead of fiddling with internals. See the KOMA-Script manual for more information about commands \KOMAoption and \KOMAoptions and option open and the supported values any, left, and right.
If you use another class, see the user manual of the class, whether it provides similar features.
Caveat: There may be packages, that evaluate \if@openright only at load time but not at runtime and therefore do not react on \@openrightfalse or \@openrighttrue after having been loaded. But currently I do not know any such package.

Thank you. When doing it this way, in the preamble, is it correct that openright must be true in the declaration of the document class? It seems that it had to be openany when using the approach in my question; and, when trying this method in the preamble, some chapters started on the left if not openright in the document class.

If you use \mainmatter you usually also use \frontmatter. And my change of \frontmatter already switch to openany for book by setting \@openrightfalse resp. explicitly switch to open=any for scrbook. BTW: If you need a complete example in the answer, you should also show a MWE in the question.
